# SQL> Selecting Multiple Sums Given Unique Conditions from Diff. Tables

Tags: mysql, sql-server, xampp

First and foremost I'd like to apologize if the title was in any way misleading. This is my first time here on StackOverflow and I'm also still learning SQL. Anyway, I'm working on a little question for an assignment for an into to SQL unit in school.

I'll give some background for the question.
A city's hockey association has an SQL database, and whoever's doing the question is presumed to be someone asked to get certain information off the database.

This question asks you to use SUM to display a sum of fees paid only by players who have paid in full, from two separate leagues (tables). That means, one sum per league, so 2 sums.

For the first league, the Competitive players in tblCompPlayers have to pay 300$ for their season.
In the second league, the Recreational players in tblRecPlayers have to pay 125$ for their season.

There are players in each table who have paid in full, paid part of the fees, or not paid at all.

What I've run into is that, doing separate select SUM statements only turns up a result for the last select statement executed.

What I want to accomplish is that I want to show the two sums side by side in separate rows, despite the columns they are from having thesame title-- and the tables they're being drawn from are different.

I've ended up using case statements at this point, as I've gotten the side-by-side bit down

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN tblCompPlayers.FeesPaid = 300 THEN tblCompPlayers.FeesPaid END) AS "Total of Comp. Fees Paid in Full",
       SUM(CASE WHEN tblRecPlayers.FeesPaid = 125 THEN tblRecPlayers.FeesPaid END) AS "Total of Rec. Fees Paid in Full"
FROM tblCompPlayers, tblRecPlayers
```

This turns up the following table

```
Total of Comp. Fees Paid in Full | Total of Rec. Fees Paid in Full 
---------------------------------|-----------------------------------------
28800.00                         | 13000.00
```

However, when I manually went through and calculated the sums, they were 2400 for Comp Fees, and 1000 for Rec. Fees

I know something's wrong, but at this point I've backed myself into a corner on where to go from here, I can't figure it out haha

Any help here would be appreciated. I might be overcomplicating this.. The only other way I can see to answer this question would be to do 2 separate queries, one to calculate the sum for Comp, one for Rec, but that does not fulfill the requirements of the question

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for here is a pair of subqueries, like this:

```
SELECT 
(SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN tblCompPlayers.FeesPaid = 300 THEN tblCompPlayers.FeesPaid END) FROM tblCompPlayers) AS "Total of Comp. Fees Paid in Full"
, (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN tblRecPlayers.FeesPaid = 125 THEN tblRecPlayers.FeesPaid END) FROM tblRecPlayers) AS "Total of Rec. Fees Paid in Full"
```

It's not the prettiest query I've ever seen, but I'm sure it'll do the job.